# What are the chances of an event given an expected time (with distribution) and a current time

Tags: statistics

Scenario is.. Lets say I receive 100 letters a day. How I receive the letters more or less resembles a Gaussian distribution centered around the middle of the day. One of these days I expect to receive letter X.

Question 1. Given the time of day what is my chance of still receiving letter x. integrating my knowledge of how my letters are distributed thought the day.

Question 2. Can I say minutes into the day that I already have ... a 98% chance of receiving the letter.

Also. my example is bound (1 Day) ... so at the end of the day if I do not receive the letter, then my chances of still receiving fall to 0%. how do I do it for an unbound example...so if I receive the bulk of letters 7 days after they are sent, what are the odds I may receive a letter 5 years after it was sent?

I'm a novice to statistics. so please be kind :) Very Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to "cheat" in order to "squeeze" a normal distribution in a 24-hour period. Technically, the normal distribution has support $(-\infty, +\infty)$.

But you did say 'more or less', so let's try to get an approximate solution:
On a 24-hour clock, I suppose you'd want $\mu = 12$ (noon). Then you'd need
a standard deviation short enough to include essentially all of the normal
probability within a 12-hr period on both sides. Maybe make $\sigma = 3$ hours.
Then you get "almost all" of your letters in the interval $\mu \pm 3\sigma$
(that is, between 3am and 9pm). Mere fanciful fractions of letters would
be 'received' before 3am or after 9pm. (Total probability .0027.)

[Technically, you'd have to truncate the normal
to ignore any probability beyond $\mu \pm 4\sigma.$ But that probability is
negligible, so the truncated normal and the original normal are indistinguishable
for practical purposes. You could use an 4-parameter beta distribution or 'extended beta distribution' to put a proper distribution on the interval
$(0, 24)$ with mean at 12--and no messy tiny bits of probability left over.
See Wikipedia on 'beta distribution' if you want to pursue this.]

(1) By 3pm (15 on a 24 hour clock or $\mu + \sigma$) you'd have about 84 of your 100 letters. That is, the 'standard score' of 3pm is $Z = (15-12)/3 = 1$ and a printed
table of the standard normal distribution has $P(Z \le 1) = .8413.$

(2) The 98th percentile of $Norm(12, 3)$ is 18.16125, which you can get
by standardizing and looking at a printed table of the standard normal 
distribution. So on a typical day you'd have 98 of your 100 letters by 6:10 pm.

Sorry, I can't make much sense of your last paragraph. If you can re-phrase it,
maybe someone can answer.